# XMLHTTPRequest from mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, shell

I am replicating a collection (I only have access to mongo shell on the server). In the current collection all documents have a field called `jsonURL`. The value of this field is a url `http://www.something.com/api/abc.json`. I want to copy each document from oldCollection to newCollection, but I want also want to fetch data from that url and add that to each new document created.

I last time heard that `XMLHTTPRequest` was on mongo's list, but as a low priority feature (I can understand why). And as I found nothing in the documentation, I am guessing its still in the queue. I am hoping I can get something in `forEach(function(eachDoc){});`

Do I have any other way of achieving this. Thanks.

Comment: If you can connect to the port that MongoDB listens on from a remote computer, you can use Node.js and the child_process API to execute wget or curl or similar. See https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html . This presumes you are using a Mac or *nix shell from which to start your script. You will need the MongoDB Javascript driver.